# php pdo object in an array

Tags: php, pdo

there

I want dynamic sql ($updateStock[$key]) can execute.

I push value into array $updateBindValue['itemQuantity'][$itemIndex] and $updateBindValue['itemID'][$itemIndex].

I try many times but I dont know where is problem.

Is possible pdo object array can execute or not.

```
foreach ($item['item'] as $itemIndex => $itemValue) {
    $updateStock[$itemIndex] = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE stock SET inStock = inStock + :itemQuantity WHERE id = :itemID");
    $updateBindValue['itemQuantity'][$itemIndex] = $itemValue['itemQuantity'];
    $updateBindValue['itemID'][$itemIndex] = $itemValue['itemID'];

}   

$PDO->beginTransaction();
foreach ($updateStock as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    $updateStock[$key]->bindValue(":itemQuantity",$updateBindValue['itemQuantity'][$key]);
    $updateStock[$key]->bindValue(":itemID",$updateBindValue['itemID'][$key]);
    $updateStock[$key]->execute();

}
$PDO->commit();
```

Comment: You want us to help you but all you say is `"I code this as following , but it dose'nt work"`. Put some effort in, and get effort in return.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about what you except. I see no reason to have more than one prepared statement in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I cant exactly express what I wanna say. My English is poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need array of PDOStatements:

```
$updateSmt = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE stock SET inStock = inStock + :itemQuantity WHERE id = :itemID");

$PDO->beginTransaction();
foreach ($item['item'] as $itemIndex => $itemValue) {
    $updateSmt->bindValue(":itemQuantity",$itemValue['itemQuantity']);
    $updateSmt->bindValue(":itemID",$itemValue['itemID']);
    $updateSmt->execute();
}
$PDO->commit();
```

Comment: Nothing to sorry for.